# About releasing memory when using pygame and Python

Tags: python, pygame

For example, a projectile flies off screen, does the program still compute its location, speed, etc.?

If so, how to release it?

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from sys import exit

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480), 0, 32)

background = pygame.image.load(background_image_filename).convert()
sprite = pygame.image.load(sprite_image_filename)


x = 0.

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            exit()

    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    screen.blit(sprite, (x, 100))
    x+= 10.
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the location, speed, etc. still have to be computed, otherwise no object that is off-screen could ever enter the screen area again. Pygame is smart enough not to attempt to render these objects.

It's usually advisable to use [pygame sprites and sprite groups](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=introduction_to_sprites&lang=en#section_13) which allow you to remove sprites simply by calling `self.kill()`. You could also use lists or sets to store your objects, but then you have to write a bit more code yourself.

So I'd first define a `pygame.Rect` (the `game_area`) with the size of your screen or a bit larger (in the example below I use a smaller one). Rects have a `contains` method that you can use to check if your sprite's rect is inside the `game_area` rect. If the sprite is outside, just call `self.kill()` and pygame will remove the sprite from all associated sprite groups.

```
import random

import pygame as pg
from pygame.math import Vector2


class Projectile(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, game_area):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pg.Surface((5, 5))
        self.image.fill(pg.Color('aquamarine2'))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.vel = Vector2(2, 0).rotate(random.randrange(360))
        self.pos = Vector2(pos)
        self.game_area = game_area

    def update(self):
        self.pos += self.vel
        self.rect.center = self.pos
        if not self.game_area.contains(self.rect):
            self.kill()


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    game_area = pg.Rect(60, 60, 520, 360)
    game_area_color = pg.Color('aquamarine2')
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group(Projectile(game_area.center, game_area))

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True

        all_sprites.add(Projectile(game_area.center, game_area))
        all_sprites.update()

        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        all_sprites.draw(screen)
        pg.draw.rect(screen, game_area_color, game_area, 2)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does, but since you have only a single projectile (incremented using x), you can easily choose what to do using a few if statements. The process becomes harder when there are multiple projectiles (which you need to store in a container), you should apply this.

Here is an example

```
for projectile in projectile_list:

    # Check if the position is inside the screen
    if 0 < projectile.x < WIDTH and 0 < projectile.y < HEIGHT:
         # Do position operations
```

This way, you only process what is required. You can apply similar method to remove unused projectiles from the list or whatever container you are using.

Comment: thank you, I get it. I guess a simple group container will solve this problem